# Cannot find name Select - Ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I followed this tutorial : https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ion-select-with-icon/63059/10 **check last solution**.

I want show select option menu on clicking an icon (which is placed on a header)
like below:

[image]

**But I get error : cannot find name 'Select', because of this build fails.**

## code

```
<ion-buttons end> 
 <button ion-button icon-only (click)="someFunc()" >
  <ion-icon name="icon-name"></ion-icon>
 </button>
</ion-buttons>

<ion-select #sectionSelect (ngModel)="selecteTopic" [selectOptions]="selectOptions" (ionChange)="topicChange($event,selecteTopic)">
  <ion-option value="0" selected="true">topic A</ion-option>
  <ion-option value="1">topic B</ion-option>
  <ion-option value="2">topic C</ion-option>
  <ion-option value="3">topic D</ion-option>
  <ion-option value="4">topic E</ion-option>
  <ion-option value="5">topic F</ion-option>
  <ion-option value="6">topic G</ion-option>
  <ion-option value="7">topic H</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

## typescript file

```
//Error here - cannot find name 'Select'
@ViewChild('sectionSelect') sectionSelect: Select;

selectOptions  =  {
  title: 'Location',
  subTitle: 'Select outlet location'
};

import { Component ,ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

someFunc(){
    this.sectionSelect.open();
    console.log('hello')
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you import the `Select`.

```
import { Select } from 'ionic-angular';
```